# Deselect multiline selection to single last selection

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

[Looking at the documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)

> To go from multiple selections to a single selection, press Escape.

However, this always takes me to the first selection, I would like to go to the last selection, is there a plugin or command for this?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Sublime-MultiEditUtils](https://github.com/philippotto/Sublime-MultiEditUtils) and press `shift+esc` to [jump to last region](https://github.com/philippotto/Sublime-MultiEditUtils#jump-to-last-region).